# livewire I'm facing problem in submit form value getting null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I'm new in laravel livewire I'm getting null value in extended component inputs. extended means I'm linked 1st component inside 2nd component.
1st component having submit button 2nd component having inputs when I submit form im getting input null.
and im keeping every thing in single component it works. help me to fix.

> my 1st component Application //handling submit
> //livewire view

```
<div>
 <form  wire:submit.prevent="submit"> 
 <input type="text" wire:model="application_id">
 @livewire('EnrollmentForm')   
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">SAVE</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

//livewire controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class Application extends Component
{
    
    public $application_id;
    public $name;
    public $middel_name;
    public $last_name;

     protected $rules = [

'application_id' => 'required|min:6',
'name' => 'required|min:6',
'middel_name' => 'required|min:6',
'last_name' => 'required|min:6',

    ];

    public function submit() 
    {
          $this->validate();
 $input['application_id'] =   ucwords(strtolower($this->application_id));
 $input['name'] =   ucwords(strtolower($this->name));
 $input['middel_name'] =   ucwords(strtolower($this->middel_name));
 $input['last_name'] =   ucwords(strtolower($this->last_name));
 
 User::create($input);
    }
}
```

> my 2nd component EnrollmentForm //Inputs this linked in Application component
> //livewire view

```
  <div>
     
     <input type="text" wire:model="name">
     <input type="text" wire:model="middel_name">
     <input type="text" wire:model="last_name">

  </div>
```

//livewire controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;


class EnrollmentForm extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $middel_name;
    public $last_name;
 
}
```

Comment: So I'm trying to understand here;you're using 2 separate Livewire components yet expecting the data to be returned to 1 single component? Are you using a Livewire component as a Blade component (a.k.a. code snippet)? Because that's not the use for Livewire

Comment: In Livewire v2, all components are completely isolated. You can communicate between them, but doesn't look like that's the best way to solve your issue. Basically all you need here is to put everything into the same component, the HTML and everything

Comment: @Qirel i what to  reuse that 2nd component in project so may time in different place so im doing like this. is there any way to full feel my this concept

Comment: Yes, you can use a blade-component or a view rather than a Livewire component. For Livewire v3 which was released for beta today, you would be able to model up to the parent, but keep in mind that v3 is in beta, not released in stable version yet.

Comment: @Yinci this is livewire view

Comment: @Qirel I checked livewire 2 doc there is event emit and listeners but I'm qunfus with send data to submit function on input

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see here is that you are missing `</form>` (If you tried to open it in one component and close in nested - won't work:

```
<div>
 <form  wire:submit.prevent="submit"> 
 <input type="text" wire:model="application_id">
 @livewire('EnrollmentForm')   
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Second thing I see here is nesting components without any need for it. You have basic form so you should put all inside one component (merge those 2 classes and blades into one).

But if you REALLY want to do it, then you should consider using a lot of emits.

For example, in first component you need only one `public property` because your form in first component has only 1 field that it is providing.

In other component class you should have 3 `public properties` because your form has 3 of them. Also, you need in this case `rules` in second component, too. Because they are not going to take rules from the first component.

After you move all these around, you will basically need to take all 3 data from second component into 1 array and on change you will need to do something like:

```
public $mySecondArrayData = [];


public function updatedMySecondArrayData($data) {
    //take all the data here

   // and send it to the parent component either with $this->emit(---) or $this->emitUp(...);
}
```

And in parent component then you need to listen for that event like:

```
protected $listeners = ['emitNameFromChildComponent']
```

And then in new array take these data from child component so you can actually submit them in your form too.

Yeah there are some stuff I didn't cover but I can't write 2 full components codes here :D

Hopefully this will help you even though this doesn't make sense to me at all since you can make this form work in 5min (if you are learning livewire then in  30min so you can understand everything :D )

Comment: can you write that code i can under stand easily

Comment: @user12931578 which one?

Comment: above I provided my code, and you explained how to solve that problem, but I don't get it , please fix my code as you are telling

Comment: @user12931578 not sure if that is the point of the SO. You just need to follow instructions I provided.

Here are links that might help you even more.

`Array validation: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/livewire-array-validation`

`Livewire parameters in events: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#passing-parameters`

`LW Nesting components: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components`

And to be honest that is about it.